# The ampleness of canonical sheaves and the proof of "$X \simeq \mathrm{Proj}\left(\bigoplus_k H^0(X, \omega_X^k)\right)$".

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, derived-categories

In Bondal and Orlov's paper, ''Reconstruction of a variety from the derived category and groups of autoequivalences'' (http://www.mi-ras.ru/~orlov/papers/Compositio2001.pdf), I think that they use the following result:

> Let X be the smooth projective variety, $\omega_X$ is the canonical
>   sheaf of $X$. If $\omega_X$ is ample,
>   $$X \simeq\mathrm{Proj}\left(\bigoplus_k H^0(X, \omega_X^k)\right). $$

I am looking for a complete proof of this fact. I have read some literature, but the proof is omitted in them. Is this a simple fact? Could you tell me the proof or the literature on which it is listed?

Comment: If $R=\oplus_{k\geq 0} R_k$ with $R_0=K$, the base field and $R$ finitely generated $K$-algebra, then consider $S=\oplus_{n|k} R_k\subset R$ for some integer $n>0$. One easily checks that there is an induced isomorphism $\mathrm{Proj}\,R\to\mathrm{Proj}\, S$. In your case, $\omega_X$ is ample, so for a large enough $n$, $\omega_X^n$ is very ample. Rest should be clear.